# can't connect to Socket.IO server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, socket.io

I want to host my frontend on Vercel (I'm using Nextjs) and since it doesn't support socket connections in it's API routes I decided to move this part of my app to Heroku. My problem is that when I use the server from my frontend in dev environment it works just fine, but when I deploy it to Heroku I get this error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-socket-server.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NMPkkyL' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

my server code looks like this:

```js
import express from 'express';
import io, { Namespace } from 'socket.io';
import { PORT, menus, socketServerConfig, adminRoom } from './util/config';

const server = express().listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`)
);
const socketServer = io(server, socketServerConfig);

const attachSocketHandlers = (server: Namespace) => {
  server.on('connection', socket => {
    const handlers = {
      'admin-log-in': () => {
        socket.join(adminRoom);
      },
      'need-waiter': (table: Table) => {
        server.to(adminRoom).emit('need-waiter', table);
      },
      'need-receipt': (table: Table) => {
        server.to(adminRoom).emit('need-receipt', table);
      },
      order: (order: Order) => {
        server.to(adminRoom).emit('order', order);
      },
      disconnect: () => {
        socket.leaveAll();
      },
    };

    Object.entries(handlers).map(([event, handler]) => {
      socket.on(event, handler);
    });
  });
};

menus.forEach(menu => {
  const namespacedServer = socketServer.of(`/${menu}`);
  attachSocketHandlers(namespacedServer);
});
```

What I understood from the socket.io docs is that if you list no origins in the config it allows all origins to access the socket server.This is my socketServerConfig:

```js
import { ServerOptions } from 'socket.io';

const defaultPort = 4000;

export const PORT = process.env?.PORT ?? defaultPort;

export const menus = ['more'];

export const adminRoom = 'admin';

export const socketServerConfig: ServerOptions = {
  serveClient: false, // i don't serve any static files
};
```

this is how I connect from my frontend:

```js
const url = 'https://my-socket-server.herokuapp.com/';
const io = connect(`${url}${menu}`);
```

I tried various solutions from SOF but I just can't get it to work, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing npm install cors and adding this to your server:

```
const cors = require('cors');
const whitelist = [
  'http://localhost:3000',
  YOUR FRONTEND URL
];
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    console.log('** Origin of request ' + origin);
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      console.log('Origin acceptable');
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      console.log('Origin rejected');
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
};
express().use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Hope this helped!